# Перегрузка операторов !, (), [] для работы со строками

Tags: c#, c#-7.0, override

Была поставлена задача перегрузить операторы `!`, `()`, `[]` для работы со строками. Оператор `!` перегрузить оказалось не сложно, а вот с `()` и `[]` возникли проблемы, можно что-нибудь сделать?

**UPD**

Гугл говорит, что операторы `()`, `[]` нельзя перегрузить, но препод очень просит

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, **в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д**. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: [Операторы C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/), [перегружаемые операторы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/overloadable-operators)

Comment: [] - это свойство-индексатор, с ним проблем не должно быть. ! - перегружается нормально. () - это не оператор и перегрузить его нельзя (если только не имеется ввиду оператор проведения типов, с коим тоже проблем быть не должно, см. ключевые слова implicit и explicit)

Comment: `но препод очень просит` - покажите ему документацию. Ну или пусть расшифрует, что он имеет ввиду по "перегрузить".

Comment: @rdorn: ради препода можно и сотворить невозможное хД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"возникли проблемы" - опять игра "Угадай-ка!"?

**Indexer:**

```
public string this[string str]
{
  get { return "abc_" + str; }
  set { // use str and value }
}
```

Перегружаемые операторы в C#:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/overloadable-operators